# Pythons ThreadPoolExecutor Seems to not be working as intended

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

Thanks for taking the time to help if you are reading this!

I am thinking that my use of the ThreadPoolExecutor is not working in python. The code is running without errors and correct output, but it is not running concurrently as desired. I believe this is the case because one of my batch runs takes 10 hours to run when the longest individual run takes ~4 hours to run individually, and I have more than enough cores to just run all of my individual runs at once.

my code works as such:

```
import a 
import b 
import c 
import d 
import e 
from f import g
from t import q

funcs = [a.func1, b.func2, [g.func3, g.func4, e.func5], c.func8, d.func6, [q.func9, q.func10]


def check_and_run(funcs, out_text: str = "") -> str:
    if type(funcs) == list:
        for func in funcs:
            out_text = check_and_run(func, out_text=out_text)
        return out_text
    else:
        func = funcs
        try:
            out_text = func(out_text=out_text)
            return out_text
        except AttributeError as attr:
            if str(attr) == "'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'":
                return f"{out_text}\nERROR - check command line - {str(func)}"
        except Exception as e:
            return f"{out_text}\nERROR:\t{func.__name__}, \t{str(e)}"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=default_num_cores) as executor:
   for routine_or_list_of_routines in list_of_routines:
        out_result = executor.submit(check_and_run, funcs)
        temp = out_result.result()
        temp = "".join(i for i in temp) if type(temp) == list else temp
        out_text = f"{out_text}{temp}"
```

I have a list of one of two items, a function to run or a list of functions to run (some runs are dependent on other runs). Every function takes the same a string and appends whether it ran or not (for printing purposes to check its status after the end of the batch run).

Wondering if anyone would have a hunch as to why this doesn't work. Also willing to look at alternative solutions, but I have struggled with implementations from multiprocessing package before. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you use multiprocessing Pool instead of Threading pool. Threads share the resources of one single process, so you are always limited.

Here's the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I would suggest to use numba automatic parallelization. Check the documentation 
here.  https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/parallel.html

Comment: What is `list_of_routines`? And it looks like you're always submitting the complete `funcs` as argument?

Comment: It looks strange that you are `.submit`ting and then collecting (`.result()`) for each round in the loop: that's not concurrent? You should submit _all_ tasks and only afterwards collect _all_ results?

Comment: hmmm that might be where the problem lies, ```list_of_routines``` is a list of 1 of 2 elements, a function or a list of functions, when passed to check and run, it just runs the function if its a function or loops through the list and runs the functions (some of my daily data runs are dependent on prior runs) THanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Timus in the comments, the time to run came in around half as fast as expected meaning threading is working. I updated the code as follows:

```
Thanks for taking the time to help if you are reading this!

I am thinking that my use of the ThreadPoolExecutor is not working in python. The code is running without errors and correct output, but it is not running concurrently as desired. I believe this is the case because one of my batch runs takes 10 hours to run when the longest individual run takes ~4 hours to run individually, and I have more than enough cores to just run all of my individual runs at once.

my code works as such:

import concurrent.futures
import a 
import b 
import c 
import d 
import e 
from f import g
from t import q

funcs = [a.func1, b.func2, [g.func3, g.func4, e.func5], c.func8, d.func6, [q.func9, q.func10]


def check_and_run(funcs, out_text: str = "") -> str:
    if type(funcs) == list:
        for func in funcs:
            out_text = check_and_run(func, out_text=out_text)
        return out_text
    else:
        func = funcs
        try:
            out_text = func(out_text=out_text)
            return out_text
        except AttributeError as attr:
            if str(attr) == "'functools.partial' object has no attribute '__name__'":
                return f"{out_text}\nERROR - check command line - {str(func)}"
        except Exception as e:
            return f"{out_text}\nERROR:\t{func.__name__}, \t{str(e)}"

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=default_num_cores) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(check_and_run, routine_or_list_of_routines) for
                  routine_or_list_of_routines in list_of_routines]
        str_lst = []
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            str_lst.append(future.result())
    out_text = "".join(str_lst)
```

Thanks everyone!